# Creating piechart in bokeh from a JSON file

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, bokeh

My need is to read a JSON  data file and create a chart on it. I know I have to use panda data frames.

My JSON looks like

```
[    {
       "name": "Anand",
       "task": "development",  
     },  
        .....  
]
```

Code so far

```
from bokeh.charts import donut,show,output_file
from bokeh.charts.utils import df_from_json

import pandas as pd

df=df_from_json('the path of the file')
d= Donut(df,label=['name', 'task'],values='task',text_font_size='8pt')
output_file("donut.html")
show(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wedge` directly:

```
from math import pi

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

p = figure(x_range=(-1.2, 1.2), y_range=(-1.2, 1.2))

p.wedge(x=0 , y=0, radius=1, start_angle=0, end_angle=0.75*pi, color="red")
p.wedge(x=0 , y=0, radius=1, start_angle=0.75*pi, end_angle=1.05*pi, color="blue")
p.wedge(x=0 , y=0, radius=1, start_angle=1.05*pi, end_angle=1.55*pi, color="green")
p.wedge(x=0 , y=0, radius=1, start_angle=1.55*pi, end_angle=2*pi, color="orange")

output_file("foo.html")

show(p)
```

Here I have made separate calls to `wedge` but you could also put all the data into arrays/columns and pass everything to a single call to `wedge`.

[image]